# How to regid station data into grid data in R

Tags: r, grid, geospatial, kriging, automap

I have some station data and I am trying to regrid the station data into grid data. I have tried the `autoKrige`function but an error occurs. I wonder if someone can help me, thanks.

The test data can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/68euncqtb3oijw5/testdata.rdata?dl=0

```
load("testdata.rdata",.GlobalEnv)
library(automap)
library(rgdal)

coordinates(newgrid) <- ~x+y
names(Mydata)[1:2]=c("x","y")
coordinates(Mydata) <- ~x+y

Krig=matrix(nrow = nrow(newgrid@coords),ncol = 30)
for( i in 1:30) {
  Krig[,i] = autoKrige(Mydata[,i],input_data=Mydata,new_data = newgrid)$krige_output$var1.pred
}

`Error: too many spatial dimensions: 328`
```